# Through VBA, need to control hidden items in slicer

Tags: vba, excel

I have an objective where in I would need to select single item in a slicer called Client, do some functionality and select the next item in the same slicer & repeat the process. 
I am really not a professional in VBA, but wrote a code that would do the job. However in the process the items which do not have the data or hidden items in the same slicers are also getting selected, which should not happen. Can someone please help me with this piece of code and How I can control to select only the visible items in the slicer and stop running once I am done with the visible items.

Here is the code that run for me:

```
Sub Test()
Dim slItem As SlicerItem
Dim i As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Client")
'deselect all items except the first
    .SlicerItems(1).Selected = True
    For Each slItem In .VisibleSlicerItems
        If slItem.Name <> .SlicerItems(1).Name Then _
            slItem.Selected = False
    Next slItem
'step through each item and run custom function
    For i = 2 To .SlicerItems.Count
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = True
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance